# Min weighted edge cover - is the greedy algorithm sub-optimal?

Tags: graphs, optimization, combinatorics

The post here: [Solving the min edge cover using the maximum matching algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110819/solving-the-min-edge-cover-using-the-maximum-matching-algorithm) provides a way to obtain the min edge cover from a maximum matching by greedily adding edges on top of the maximum matching until all vertices are covered. Now, thinking about the min-weighted edge cover problem, it would seem this approach can be extended. First, find the [minimum weighted matching with maximum edges](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132737/maximum-cardinality-matching-of-maximum-weight), and then add edges of the smallest weight greedily, smallest weight ones first.

However, reading section 19.3 of the book "Combinatorial optimization: polyhedra and efficiency" by Schrijver, a more complicated algorithm is presented. This makes it seem like my approach above is sub-optimal. Is it possible to find a counter-example, preferably on a bi-partite graph where my greedy algorithm would fail to provide an optimal solution? I haven't been able to find one with some toy graphs.

Comment: "First, find the minimum weighted edge cover" -- that is the top-level problem you're trying to solve, so I think you meant something else here. But it's not clear what, since if you meant "the minimum-weight matching", that would be the empty matching (assuming positive edge weights), while "the maximum-weight matching" will certainly give you suboptimal solutions in certain cases (consider, e.g., a square in which 2 opposite edges have high weight and the other two edges have low weight).

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Good catch. I meant the matching of maximal size that has the minimum weight. I suppose this isn't easy to find?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but if negative weights can be used in a max-weight matching algorithm, then this could be used to find a matching of maximal size having minimum weight: First negate all edge weights, then add in all missing edges with a tiny negative weight. Now find the max-weight matching, and then discard all edges in it that you just added.

Comment: Can you clarify "missing edges"? In section 17.2 of Schrijver, when describing the Hungarian method, he requires a weight function $w: E \to Q$ so I suppose negative weights are possible.

Comment: I just meant any edges not already present in the input graph. That's good news about the Hungarian method, but as you can see I found a counterexample anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to your proposed algorithm:

[image]

The optimal solution consists of 3 edges and costs 3+1+1=5, but the min-cost maximum-cardinality matching, which consists of 2 edges and costs 3+3=6, will be chosen by the first step of your algorithm and immediately returned, as it is already a solution. (The only other maximum-cardinality matching costs 1+6=7.)